# Is there a recording of Beethoven's 9th - 4th Movment w/ no chorus

Tags: classical-music

Title fairly well summarizes the question - I really enjoy Beethoven's 9th, esp. the 4th movement, and would really like to hear the orchestration without the chorus. I've tried some amount of Google-fu but have been unsuccessful in identifying if there are any recordings of just the orchestration (which has some beautiful oboe and clarinet lines) without the vocals.

Comment: Why?  That's like wanting to hear the 3rd movement without the second violins.  Now, if you just want to concentrate on the instrumental part, that just takes some ear-training.  You might find it helpful to read along in the score while listening.

Comment: the ear training I have is what has led me to ask the question :)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft a technique I find useful is to sing one part from the score as I listen to the recording, or to play it on a keyboard.  Surely hearing any movement without some part is a useful exercise that enhances ear training.

Answer (score 2):

There is one in your future.  You could visit a rehearsal with the orchestra before they bring in the choir.  This may be the only way to get a recording.  Neat question that is for sure.  Beethoven's ninth is so full of intriguing passages.  You may need to massage some connections with powerful music personalities in your locality.

Comment: most professional orchestras would frown upon surreptitious recording of a rehearsal for numerous reasons: among them quality control, union, recording agreements in their contracts, etc...

Comment: @NKCampbell you could hire an orchestra for the purpose of producing such a recording, however.  It would be costly, but not insurmountably so, especially if you could collect a group of people with similar interests to share the costs.

Answer (score 2):

One idea is, to try a recording of the piano transcription by Liszt, e. g. with [Scherbakov](http://www.naxos.com/catalogue/item.asp?item_code=8.557366). Definitely no chorus there. Of course it has to be checked, whether your woodwind solos are recognizable here, but I found my brain to supply from memory some tone colors the piano was unable to provide.